# Need help regarding duplicates records in JAVA

Tags: java, class, arraylist

[image: Here, I attached image file with my output and expected output. I have a problem for duplicate records.]

Here, I wrote my code with my output. I do not know about how to work with duplicate records.

```
class Price{
    int productID,totalSold=0,totalPrice=0;
    double price;
    public Price(int productID,double price) {
        this.price= price;
        this.productID=productID;
    }   
}
class Slips{
    int personID, productID, numberOfSold,product1Sold,product2Sold,product3Sold,product4Sold,performance;
    public Slips(int personID,int productID,int numberOfSold)
    {
        this.personID=personID;
        this.productID=productID;
        this.numberOfSold=numberOfSold;
    }    
}

class PriceComparator implements Comparator<Price>{
    public int compare(Price p1,Price p2)
    {
        return Integer.compare(p2.totalPrice, p1.totalPrice);
    }
}

public class PTestDec2009 {

    static ArrayList<Price> ALPrice=new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Slips> ALSlips=new ArrayList<>();    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        getPriceInfo("C:\\Users\\Mayank Patel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PTestDec2009\\src\\ptestdec2009\\price.txt");
        getSlipsInfo("C:\\Users\\Mayank Patel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PTestDec2009\\src\\ptestdec2009\\slips.txt");
        updateSalability();        
        updateSalesPersonPerformance();
    }

    private static void getPriceInfo(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String line=null;
        BufferedReader bufferReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        while((line=bufferReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(line);
            while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                ALPrice.add(new Price(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()),Double.parseDouble(tokenizer.nextToken())));
            }
        }       
    }

    private static void getSlipsInfo(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String line=null;
        BufferedReader bufferReader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        while((line=bufferReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(line);
            while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                ALSlips.add(new Slips(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken())));                
                //updateSalesPersonPerformance(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));                
            }      
        }
    }

    private static void updateSalesPersonPerformance()
    {        
        for(int plooper=0;plooper<ALPrice.size();plooper++)
        {
            for(int slooper=0;slooper<ALSlips.size();slooper++)
            {
                if(ALPrice.get(plooper).productID == ALSlips.get(slooper).productID)
                { 
                   switch (ALSlips.get(slooper).productID) {
                        case 1:                         
                            ALSlips.get(slooper).product1Sold += ALSlips.get(slooper).numberOfSold;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ALSlips.get(slooper).product2Sold += ALSlips.get(slooper).numberOfSold;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ALSlips.get(slooper).product3Sold += ALSlips.get(slooper).numberOfSold;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            ALSlips.get(slooper).product4Sold += ALSlips.get(slooper).numberOfSold;
                            break;
                        default:                            
                            break;
                    }
                    ALSlips.get(slooper).performance += ALPrice.get(plooper).price* ALSlips.get(slooper).numberOfSold;
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println("\nPERSONID"+"\t"+"PRODUCT1"+"\t"+"PRODUCT2"+"\t"+"PRODUCT3"+"\t"+"PRODUCT4"+"\t"+"PERFORMANCE");
        for(int slooper=0;slooper<ALSlips.size();slooper++)
        {           
           System.out.println(ALSlips.get(slooper).personID+"\t\t"+ALSlips.get(slooper).product1Sold+"\t\t"+ALSlips.get(slooper).product2Sold+"\t\t"+ALSlips.get(slooper).product3Sold+"\t\t"+ALSlips.get(slooper).product4Sold+"\t\t"+ALSlips.get(slooper).performance);
        }        
    }

    private static void updateSalability() {
     for(int plooper=0;plooper<ALPrice.size();plooper++)
        {
            for(int slooper=0;slooper<ALSlips.size();slooper++)
            {
                if(ALPrice.get(plooper).productID == ALSlips.get(slooper).productID)
                {
                    ALPrice.get(plooper).totalSold += ALSlips.get(slooper).numberOfSold;
                    ALPrice.get(plooper).totalPrice += ALPrice.get(plooper).price * ALSlips.get(slooper).numberOfSold;                      
                }               
            }
        }
     Collections.sort(ALPrice,new PriceComparator());
     System.out.println("PRODUCTID"+"\t"+"TotalSold"+"\t"+"TotalPrice");
     for(int plooper=0;plooper<ALPrice.size();plooper++)
     {
        System.out.println(ALPrice.get(plooper).productID+"\t\t"+ALPrice.get(plooper).totalSold+"\t\t"+ALPrice.get(plooper).totalPrice);
     }     
    }
}
```

so please help me to get my expected output. I attached image file with my output and expected output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post images if you can do it using text, most people won't look at images and you won't get help.

Comment: thanks for your comment

Comment: Do you use JAVA8 or earlier java revisions ? There is a reason for this , you can use streams and use aggregations for it. Can you confirm ?

Comment: I am using Java8. But I don't know how to do it. Can you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this:

```
public static void removeDuplicates(){
    ArrayList<Slips> newRay = new ArrayList<Slips>();
    for(Slips s : ALSlips){
        boolean hasAlready = false;
        for(Slips d: newRay){
            if(d.personID == s.personID){
                d.product1Sold += s.product1Sold;
                d.product2Sold += s.product2Sold;
                d.product3Sold += s.product3Sold;
                d.product4Sold += s.product4Sold;
                d.numberOfSold += s.numberOfSold;
                d.performance += s.performance;
                hasAlready = true;
            }
        }
        if(!hasAlready){
            newRay.add(s);
        }
    }
    ALSlips = newRay;
}
```

I beg of you though, please rewrite this, or comment it, or something!! unless you are doing this for your job. then leave it how it is. they won't be able to fire you.

Comment: this is good way to get my expected output. But How can it to do using hashset or hashmap? can you give me some code for that? thank you very much for your help.

Comment: this is incredibly inefficient code.  Why not not break, when found?  What happens when this has thousands of elements?  Why not use a Set or HashMap?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use an ArrayList use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) or a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

The key to this Map would be the String `PRODUCTID`

presently you are `add`ing to an ArrayList, but if you `put` to your HashMap, you can try to `get` it first.  If it exists, you can update the value in it.

An example would be something like

```
HashMap myMap <String, Price val> = new HashMap <> ();

Price newPrice = ....; // like your existing code
String prodid = newPrice.getProductId ();
Price oldVal = myMap.get (prodid);
if (oldVal != null) {
  // update newPrice with sum of val
}
myMap.put (prodid, newPrice);  // will add or replace
```

Comment: what about the `Set` Collection type  in java ? i would recommend sets rather than `HashMap`

Comment: @VikrantKashyap Yes, you are right, maybe a Set would be better for enforcing uniqueness, but anyway, it is necessary to test the return value of a `get`  first

Comment: thanks for your comment. but I don't know how to use hash map ? can you write down some code for me?

Comment: @user3360610 Better to try for yourself, but I have updated my answer with some sample

Comment: @user3360610 Also, as your productId is really just a String it is better to keep it as such

Comment: I can't get you bro. Please let me know. how to do this.

Comment: What can't you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate duplicates you can use either set or hashset instead of arraylist but if your stuffing an object into a collection you need to override equals method so that you hashset treats object as duplicate based on some attribute rather than its address for example overriden equals for your problem can be

```
@Override
public String eqauls(Slips s)
{
    if(this.personId==s.personId)
          return true;
    else
         return false;
}
```

this should be placed in your slips class.
I am not completely clear about your requirement but this is how you can eliminate duplicates